# Wait 60 Seconds to Run Cron Job After Reboot Then Run Job Every 10 Minutes

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have a script that I would like to run 60 seconds after initial system reboot and then every 10 minutes after that.  I currently need two cron job listings to achieve this:

```
*/10 * * * * php myscript.php
@reboot /bin/sleep 60; php myscript.php
```

The first listing will run my cron job immediately after system boot and so I need to have the second listing to account for the on start wait time.

Is there anyway to combine the above two cron listings into one?

Comment: Are you saying that the two lines you have already meet your requirements? I wouldn't expect the first line to run immediately after system boot, unless crond just happens to start at a 10-minute boundary.